# Does xunit understand asp.net5?

Tags: xunit, asp.net5

I'm trying to get xunit wired up to test an asp.net5 application. If I create a vanilla .dll for my test project, I'm missing a bunch of references, and when I try to add mvc6, I run into problems.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Pre
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.IO'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

So, being clever, I thought I'd create my test project with the same asp.net5 template as the project being tested. This gets me the references I need and my test project compiles, but the new project structure screws the discovery. The VS test runner can't find the test .dll (no tests found), and the console test runner, if I point it to the .dll in artifacts\bin[projName]\Debug\dnx451

```
C:\NotilusTNE\Sources\Hub\[projName]\Dev\[projName]>packages\xunit.runner.con
sole.2.1.0\tools\xunit.console "artifacts\bin\[projName]Tests2\Debug\dnx451\[projName]Tests2.dll"
xUnit.net Console Runner (64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
System.InvalidOperationException: Unknown test framework: could not find xunit.d
ll (v1) or xunit.execution.*.dll (v2) in C:\NotilusTNE\Sources\Hub\[projName]\
Dev\[projName]\artifacts\bin\[projName]Tests2\Debug\dnx451
```

Has anyone got xunit successfully testing an asp.net5 application? Surely?

Answer (score 0):

Ok there's only one right way to do this. Specific versions of ASP.NET5 applications need specific versions of xunit, as explained [here](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html). Instructions followed to the letter, including creating the .dll type "Class Library (Package)". Hopefully this will be useful to someone.

Comment: Sorry, I can only guess that the page has disappeared because the target has moved, asp.net5 no longer having DNX. I haven't been following, so you're on your own.